# 'Cannot request session' when using impacket's SMB client against a Windows machine

Tags: python, linux, smb, impacket

i am running on fedora 15 ( python 2.7 )

i've tried the imapcket.smb against windows 2000 sp4 (frensh) , windows xp sp2 (frensh) , windows xp sp3 (frensh) and it worked perfectly , but when i use it against windows 7 (frensh) x64 it didn't work .

from my python :

```
>>> import impacket.smb as smb
>>> session = smb.SMB ( '*SMBSERVER' , '192.168.56.103' )
```

and i always get the following line :

```
>>> NetBIOSError ( 'Cannot request session', 240, 130 )
```

i can't understand why this is happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*SMBSERVER` is a NetBios alias that would allow to establish a SMB over NetBIOS (port 139) connection against a target Windows machine without knowing the real NetBIOS server name of the target. Since Vista on, that alias has been deprecated.

So you have two choices:

1. `session = smb.SMB ( '<TARGET NETBIOS NAME>' , '192.168.56.103' )`. You will need to know in advance the target's NetBIOS name
2. `session = smb.SMB ( '192.168.56.103' , '192.168.56.103', sess_port = 445 )`.  This will connect to target port 445 where you don't need to know the target's NetBIOS server name.